# Worklight api console request for Push

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-console

I need to get a list of users for a specific Push adapter/event source, and, I'm trying to use the API console requests, which says the format is:

```
http://{hostname}:{port}/{context-root}/console/api/{api-context}/{action}/{parameters}
```

and I'm using:

```
http://192.168.1.106:10080/Module_07_04_nativeAPIForiOSPush/console/api/Push/get/PushAdapter/PushEventSource
```

to search the demo project, which has one subscriber.  However, I get 404 return from a browser request.

The first column of the docs is the "api-context", but, it lists "Push" and "Event Sources", which, obviously seems invalid.

What is the correct format to find users subscribed to a push for a specific adapter/event source?

Answer (score 0):

WL server does not provide API for listing subscribed users. By design you should maintain your own DB of subscribed users, this is why you have onSubscribe onUnsubscribe callbacks in event source. As an alternative - you can look into WL's DB tables to find this info.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not sure what you mean "by design", you mean, by IBM's design?  Wow, I thought this was what Worklight notifications could easily do, but, here we go building it ourselves, again.  So, there is no method to perform push logic within Worklight?    This seems like a glaring omission.  So, does anyone know why these url's don't work?  The doc here is extremely vague.